# Traducción de "legacy" en el contexto de documentación

Tags: reactjs, documentacion

Traduciendo la [documentación de React](https://react.dev/) al castellano, nos ha surgido una duda con respecto a la palabra *"legacy"*. El termino que usamos para reemplazar fue «heredado» (ejemplo: código heredado, API heredada).

Sin embargo cuando se lee la documentación, se siente un poco raro usar heredado. No transmite lo mismo.

¿qué palabra podría usarse alternativamente?

Comment: Heredado no siempre es el caso, creo que se debe usar en otro contexto, por ejemplo `of, relating to, or being a previous or outdated computer system` es decir alguna tecnologia que ya esta obsoleta, aqui dejo el [vinculo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legacy).

Comment: Hay que decir que mucha literatura sí usa _código heredado_. No porque la acepción habitual de heredar se aplique al cien por ciento, eso sí. Va más por convención, es un _legacy term_ jeje